# Проблемы с параллельным парсингом

Tags: c#, парсер

Нет понимания по какой причине при запуске программы происходит моментальное завершение. Смысл заключается в том, что есть базовые ссылки, которые дают данные с локального + ещё ряд айдишников, по которым также можно обратиться на локальный сервер и получить ещё больше данных. Нужно это как можно быстрее спарсить, поэтому идея такова, что на каждый новый айдишник создаю новый поток и в нём начинаю обращаться по каждому отдельному айдишнику. Но при попытке парсинга, программа моментально завершается. Как я понимаю, завершая основной поток, либо парсинг идет по какой-то причине ооочень медленно.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Datas = new()
{
    {"Instances","http://localhost:8042/instances" },
    {"Series","http://localhost:8042/series" },
    {"Patients","http://localhost:8042/patients" },
    {"Studies","http://localhost:8042/studies" }
};

HttpClient httpClient = new();
var PatientsTask = Task.Run(() => { PatientDataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Patients")); });
var StudyTask = Task.Run(() => { StudyDataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Studies")); });
var SeriesTask = Task.Run(() => { SerieeDataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Series")); });
var InstancesTask = Task.Run(() => { InstanceDataGetter(Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Instances")); });

async Task PatientDataGetter(string url)
    
{
        var PatientsIDs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in PatientsIDs)
        {
            index++;
            Patient? patient = new Patient();
            patient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patient>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{url}/{item}"));
            patient.Path = $"{url}/{item}";
            PatientDateConverter(patient);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.Write($"Пациент {index}/{PatientsIDs.Count()}");

        }
}

async Task SerieeDataGetter(string url)
{
        var SerieeIDs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in SerieeIDs)
        {
            index++;
            Seriee? seriee = new Seriee();
            seriee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Seriee>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{url}/{item}"));
            seriee.Path = $"{url}/{item}";
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
            Console.Write($"Серия {index}/{SerieeIDs.Count()}");

        }
}
async Task InstanceDataGetter(string url)
{
    
        var InstanceIDs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in InstanceIDs)
        {
            index++;
            Instance? instance = new Instance();
            instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Instance>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{url}/{item}"));
            instance.Path = $"{url}/{item}";
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.Write($"Экземпляр {index}/{InstanceIDs.Count()}");

        }
}
async Task StudyDataGetter(string url)
{
    
        var StudyIDs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in StudyIDs)
        {
            index++;
            Study? study = new Study();
            study = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Study>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{url}/{item}"));
            study.Path = $"{Datas.GetValueOrDefault("Studies")}/{item}";
            StudyDateConverter(study);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.Write($"Исследование {index}/{StudyIDs.Count()}");

        }
}
```

Comment: 1. Закрытие из-за того, что вы не ожидаете, используете коряво `async/await`, где вместо `Task` у вас вдруг `void`. Сделайте задачи (`Task`), запустите их сколько надо, и ожидайте в конце через `Task.WhenAll()` например. 2. Медленно - потому, что вы делаете тонну лишних действий, уйма дубликатов кода. Вот к примеру, `HttpClient`, он у вас создается на каждый чих, да еще по два экземпляра... Идем в документацию и видим "HttpClient предназначен для создания экземпляра один раз и повторного использования в течение всего времени существования приложения."

Comment: Или вон например `await (await httpClient.GetAsync(url)).EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` - зачем..? Почему? `await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);` достаточно... Также на скорость влияет вывод чего либо на экран, особенно по каждому чиху. Если нужна скорость и вывод на экран, то всякие `Console.Write` заменяйте на `IProgress` и дергайте обновление например раз в 10 обновленных объектов (если они быстро обновляются конечно), а за пределами `Task` подписывайтесь на обновление и выводите на экран. Короче, избавляйтесь от дублей, и читайте про `async/await`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ то что на скорость влияет вывод на экран я прекрасно знаю, в одном потоке это все работает в разы быстрее. При этом не меняя количество задач. Сделал, в самом начале вызвал задачи  через конструкции var name= Task.Run(()=>{MethodName(Arguments));});

В конце добавил await.WhenAll();
Ничего не поменялось. Абсолютно

P.S. Возвращаемый тип методов,также, поменял

Comment: Что касается длинной конструкции, то здесь попросту идет ожидание преобразования в строку асинхронно полученного ответа страницы, далее идет дессериализация объекта. Суть не в этом, суть в том, что найти не могу где я что упускаю и почему оно не работает

Comment: Покажите изменённый код, где вы заменили `void` на `Task`.

Comment: По поводу дублирования, дублирование стоит до момента когда я разберусь с этими тасками. Потом приведу в нормальный вид. Каждом методе, где у меня были async void я поставил async Task

Comment: Изменил в основном коде темы

Comment: На кой вы влепили вызовы `Task.Run`? Уберите их. `var patientsTask = PatientDataGetter(...);` И в конце ожидание добавьте, как в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таски запустили, а ждать их кто будет?

Добавьте в конец кода

```
await Task.WhenAll(PatientsTask, StudyTask, SeriesTask, InstancesTask);
```

Запомните правило. Если есть `Task`, значит его надо где-то использовать. А ваши без дела получены были.